# How can I pass an object ID from mapped array to backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass the ID of an object to the backend. The objects are mapped from the array and there should be a separate button for each one so that the ID of each individual object can be pass to the backend.
The communication between backend and frontend works. The only problem is that the ID is not sent to the backend when the submit button is clicked. If I would now work with an OnChange and enter the ID myself in the text field, then it would work without any problems.

Does somebody has any idea?

Here my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {format} from "date-fns-tz";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import MailQueueDataService from "../services/mail_queue.service";

class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mailqueues_unsent: {},
            loading: false
        }
        this.parentClassFunction = this.parentClassFunction.bind(this);
    }

    parentClassFunction = () => {
        console.log("TEST");
        event.preventDefault();
        const url = "/api/v1/mail_queues/authorize_mail_queue";
        const { id } = this.state;

        const body = {
            id,
        };


        const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-Token": token,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }
                throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
            })
            .then(response => this.props.history.push(window.close()))
            .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child
                    parentClassFunction={this.parentClassFunction}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mail_queues_unsent: [],
            loading: false
        }
    }

    onClickSubmitButton = () =>{
        this.props.parentClassFunction()
    };

    retrieveMailQueues() {
        MailQueueDataService.getAll().then(response => {
            if (this._isMounted)
                this.setState({
                    mail_queues_unsent: response.data.mailqueues_unsent,
                    loading: false}
                )
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e)
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        this.setState({loading: true})
        this.retrieveMailQueues();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div className="col text-center"> Lade Unautorisierte Mails... </div>;
        } else {
            const {mail_queues_unsent} = this.state;
            const allMailsUnsent = mail_queues_unsent.map((mailqueues_unsent, index) => (
                <div className="col">
                    <div key={index}>
                        <h4><b>Empfänger:</b>{mailqueues_unsent.company_name}</h4>
                        <b>Datum Versandfreigabe:</b>
                        {format(new Date(mailqueues_unsent.created_at), 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm')}
                        <p><b>Anzahl der Tests:</b> {mailqueues_unsent.trials_count}</p>
                        <b>Tests:</b>
                        <p>{mailqueues_unsent.trials.map(trial => <Link to={"/trials/" + trial.id}>
                            <p>{trial.certificate_number}</p></Link>)}</p>
                        <form onSubmit={this.parentClassFunction}>
                            <label htmlFor="id"></label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="id"
                                id="id"
                                value={mailqueues_unsent.id}
                                className="form-control"
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                            <button onClick={this.onClickSubmitButton.bind(this)}>CLICK</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ));
            const noMailQueues = (
                <div>
                    <h4>
                        Kein Unautorisierte Mails vorhanden.
                    </h4>
                </div>
            );

            return (
                <div>
                    {mail_queues_unsent.length > 0 ? allMailsUnsent : noMailQueues}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling a function that is passed as prop from the parent, inside the child component you should call it on submit like this (its not this but this.props):

```
onSubmit={this.props.parentClassFunction}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint! Unfortunately didn´t solved the problem.